# Is it possible to consume ETW events from an ETL file that's being written to?

Tags: winapi, etw

If an ETL file is being written to by an active ETW session, is it safe to simultaneously consume events from it via `OpenTrace`/`ProcessTrace`?

In the absence of documentation I could find, I had assumed that ETL files were not updated atomically, and that it was first necessary to stop a session before calling `OpenTrace` to read events from it.

However, `OpenTrace` does appear to succeed even if the session is still active -- I see from Process Monitor's handle view the ETL files in use by active ETW sessions are opened with a sharing mode of `READ|DELETE`. Can we infer from this that `OpenTrace`/`ProcessTrace` will always return sensible results even for an ETL file used by an active ETW session? Does Windows use locking or some other mechanism to ensure consumers always get a consistent view of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't read events live from a `.etl` file.

But you **can** read live events from a named session, and if you specify that you are in fact doing `REALTIME` reading.

```
//Initialize an EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE to indicate the name of the session we want to read from
EVENT_TRACE_LOGFILE trace;
ZeroMemory(&trace, sizeof(trace));
trace.ProcessTraceMode = PROCESS_TRACE_MODE_REAL_TIME; //we're reading a realtime
trace.LoggerName = KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME; //i.e. "NT Kernel Logger"
trace.EventCallback = RealtimeEventCallback;

//Open the tracing session
TRACEHANDLE th = OpenTrace(trace);
if (th == INVALID_PROCESSTRACE_HANDLE)
   ThrowLastWin32Error();

//Begin processing events
DWORD res = ProcessTrace(&th, 1, nil, nil);
if (res != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    ThrowLastWin32Error();

CloseTrace(th);
```

There are a couple of these constant named loggers - defined in `EvntProv.h`:

```
KERNEL_LOGGER_NAME = "NT Kernel Logger";
GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME = "GlobalLogger";
EVENT_LOGGER_NAME  = "EventLog";
DIAG_LOGGER_NAME   = "DiagLog";
```

The other way you can start a *"named"* logging session is with:

```
xperf -start fooLoggerName -on 55F22359-9BEC-45EC-A742-311A71EEC91D
```

This starts a session named `"fooLoggerName"` for provider guid `55F22359-9BEC-45EC-A742-311A71EEC91D`.